# Regex Javascript Alphabetic with dot, not at begin or end

Tags: javascript, regex

Kia Ora,
I try to prove if a string is not empty and the used characters are just A-Za-z and the dot.
That isn't very complex and can be done with this:

```
var str = "Aj.fwfw.MMf";
var regex = new RegExp("/^[a-zA-Z.]+$/");
if(str.match(regex)) { }
```

My problem is, that I don't want to have dot at the beginning, the end or more than one dot in a row.
So things like ".fshdfhUUhd.d", "jjf." and "fff..gg" are forbidden.

Does anyone know how to solve that? I would like to put it in one regex, but if this isn't possible, than it can be also more, combined with && in the if closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z]+)*$/;
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pVdowJ/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - one or more letters
- `(?:\.[a-zA-Z]+)*` - 0+ sequences of:

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `[a-zA-Z]+` - one or more letters
- `$` - end of string.